# How to share a folder via S3 bucket policy in federated identities context?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If you want to create a central storage for logs coming from many AWS accounts and share these logs respectively with their owners, this official [AWS knowledge article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-sharing-logs.html) explains how to do this very well with IAM based users.

However, I fail to understand how to do same if you use federated identities (SAML).

Let's assume you have accounts 111111111111 and 222222222222 logging to a bucket in the account 999999999999. For simplicity, let's reference these as A1, A2 and A9.

Further, accounts A1 and A2 can be accessed by federated users allowed to assume the role ADMIN, and have CloudTrails logging to the bucket *BUCKET* in A9.

So I have so far the following bucket policy. For simplicity, statement blocks have got Sids (statement IDs) 1,2,3 and 4.

The problem:

- ADMIN from A1 can explore the folder structure in the bucket folder *AWSLogs/111111111111/** but an attempt to download an objects leads to the "access denied" error.

How comes? What is missing?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid":"1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET"
        },
        {
            "Sid":"2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/AWSLogs/111111111111/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/AWSLogs/222222222222/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid":"3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ADMIN"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "AWSLogs/111111111111/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid":"4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ADMIN"

            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/AWSLogs/111111111111/*"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: The "s3:Get*" is missing in the first Action array

Comment: applying this (add "s3:Get*" in the first Action), I get the error on saving the policy: "Conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources in statement ".

Comment: Sharing access to objects varies by the way the objects were created, and the "AWSLogs" prefix implies that these logs were created by an AWS service, which carries an additonal caveat that the role can only be a role from the same account that owns the bucket, thus this example is only viable where account 111111111111 is the owner of *both* the bucket *and* the role.  Confirm that this is what you are doing?  Otherwise you'd be able to list but not get.

Comment: Hi,  @Michael-sqlbot, thanks for your input! Your guess is right so I have extended the question to achieve full context transparency. Do you mean, the problem is that if I try to download an object, the canned ACL from Sid2 kicks in? But if so, why does the current configuration of the bucket policy still allow for browsing log folders (Sid3)?